# How to get notified about service changes to component?

Tags: angular, rxjs, components, observable

Is it possible to listen permanently to all changes in a service and transfer this information to a component?

I know that I can create an Observable in a service like below:

```
@Injectable()
export class LoadingService {
    myBool$: Observable<boolean>;

    private boolSubject: BehaviorSubject<boolean>;

    constructor() {
        this.boolSubject = new BehaviorSubject(true);
        this.myBool$ = this.boolSubject.asObservable();
    }

    set myBool(newValue) {
        console.log("set",newValue)
        this.boolSubject.next(newValue);
    }
}
```

I also know that I can have a component or a directive (like below) to subscribe to the observable to get notified about a change.

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[loading]'
})
export class LoadingDirective implements AfterViewInit {

    constructor(
    private element: ElementRef, 
    private renderer: Renderer2, 
    private loadingService: LoadingService
) {

    this.loadingService.myBool$.subscribe(response => {
        console.log("-----",response)               
    })
}
```

But I get only the first change of a service variable in the `subscribe`. How can I get all future changes (like an eventlistener) too?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: This should work and always when there is a new value being set through the service, the subscriber should get called. are you sure you don't unsubscribe at some point?

Comment: Your code should work. If it doesn't please create a [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) that reproduces your problem.

Comment: The real question is: how can I trigger a function always when observable is changed? I know that it works when I use it in HTML code, but I don't have any HTML in my scenario and want to call a function.... any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of minor things going on. First of all, in your service, you should declare the observable sequence as a `get` function, such that all new requests for it return a new observable. The way it is written is a misuse of the `BehaviorSubject`.

```
get myBool$: Observable<boolean> {
  return this.boolSubject.AsObservable();
}
```

Next, you should really take a look at the [Async Pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) in the template. Todd Motto wrote a [pretty decent article](https://toddmotto.com/angular-ngif-async-pipe) about using observables to subscribe to change of values straight from the template.

This might look like the following (it should be noted that a regular `Subject` here would be preferable as a `BehaviorSubject` will *always* return a value immediately upon subscribing):

```
<div *ngIf="myBool$ | async as value; else loading">
  <!-- use the value here? -->
  <span> {{ value }} </span>
</div>
<div #loading>
  ... loading spinner here ...
</div>
```

Comment: Hi theMayer, thank you for your answer and your support. But my problem is that I don't have any HTML-output. I need to call a function in my component (directive) when the observable is being changed. How can I achieve this?

Comment: well, I did and couldn't find a solution. Writing and asking here is always my last try...